# How do I check if gsoap is failing to serialize/send a big amount of data?

Tags: c++, gsoap

I'm running a web service client which we developed using gsoap library and we need to send 3.5 GB of data through a mutually authenticated connection - meaning we've got encrypted traffic on the network.
The server - which I have no access to - says it is receiving "empty" data.
I've made a network traffic capture and noticed a pause (a few seconds) during transmission and then an "Encrypted alert (21)" and connection closure.

Checking my code it seems there's some problem to serialize or send the data, but I haven't been able to find out exactly what's going on.

My suspicion is that gsoap is not able to allocate the necessary memory to serialize/send data.

How should I go about analyzing this?

EDIT1:
I've dropped the serialize trail and now my suspicion resides at the attachment functions. It seems defining attachment callbacks may solve my problem. Still interested in people's opinions and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems less likely that XML serialization is the cause of the problem. The standard HTTP-based communication in gsoap (i.e. without HTTP chunking) serializes the C/C++ data before sending to determine the HTTP content length. A serialization failure would show up immediately and not during transfer.

To speed up transfer of large XML chunks of data, you can optimize XML serialization with the `SOAP_XML_TREE` context flag to initialize the `struct soap` context. This reduces SOAP encoding overhead substantially. Let me explain why this is the case: the SOAP 1.1/1.2 encoding protocol incurs overhead in the gsoap engine in order to determine co-referenced elements by analyzing data structure pointers (e.g. graphs, possibly with cycles). When lots of pointers are used then this can affect the XML serializer's performance. Also, debug mode (`-DDEBUG`) will substantially slow down the gsoap engine so best to avoid with large transfers.

Perhaps a tool such as ssldump can shed some more light on the TLS/SSL communication issue you are experiencing.

Comment: I'll check this ssldump. As for the performance stuff, it seems my problem is not much about it being slow, but rather not being able to send data at all. Still think it has something to do about memory allocation failure, maybe related to attachments. Other option is some kind of search failing (I've noticed various memory searches happening in gsoap's attachment code functions).